# EWS search query with "AND" and "OR" clauses

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I am sending the following XML query to EWS using the Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync method.

The query string value needs to either match the subject or the from field; and the emails must belong the "MY_CATEGORY" category.  I am unable to enforce the last requirement. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:ItemShape>
          <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
        </m:ItemShape>
        <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="10" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
        <m:Restriction>
        <t:Or> 
           <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
             <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
             <t:Constant Value="query string" />
           </t:Contains>
           <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
             <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:From" />
             <t:Constant Value="query string" />
           </t:Contains>
        </t:Or> 
        <t:And>
          <t:Contains ContainmentMode="FullString" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Categories" />
            <t:Constant Value="MY_CATEGORY" />
          </t:Contains>
        </t:And>
        </m:Restriction>
        <m:ParentFolderIds>
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" />
        </m:ParentFolderIds>
      </m:FindItem>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories are Multivalued strings so the searchfilters your using won't work on these types of values. You can AQS on Exchange 2010 and above to search the Categories as well as the other fields your search on. eg

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
        <m:ItemShape>
          <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
          <t:AdditionalProperties>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DisplayTo" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DisplayCc" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeReceived" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:HasAttachments" />
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ItemClass" />
          </t:AdditionalProperties>
        </m:ItemShape>
        <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="250" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
        <m:SortOrder>
          <t:FieldOrder Order="Ascending">
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:DisplayName" />
          </t:FieldOrder>
        </m:SortOrder>
        <m:ParentFolderIds>
          <t:FolderId Id="AQ..." />
        </m:ParentFolderIds>
        <m:QueryString>System.Category:Green AND (From:'Glen Scales' OR Subject:test) </m:QueryString>
      </m:FindItem>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: But would this work with multiple folders?  Notice that the original query is searching the inbox and the sent folder.

Comment: Is it possible to create a EWS "Search Folder" using javascript calls?

Comment: It should work fine on multiple folders but you should try it yourself, you can create search folder using EWS eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633687(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: I cannot seem to search the Body field when I use the search folder.  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: That should be a new question with the relevant information and code, why don't you use eDiscovery if you have 2013 or greater.